# Audio Channel Issues with ALSA

Tags: sound, dell, alsa

Running a Dell XPS 13 Plus, which has a total of four speakers (2 left, 2 right).

ALSA (or something) is treating both left speakers to be the stereo pair, so audio only comes out of the left side of the device.
Left Channel Audio --> Left Speaker #1
Right Channel Audio --> Left Speaker #2

When switching to Windows, the audio works fine, so it does not appear to be a hardware issue. This issue cropped up after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10.

Here's a couple of diagnostics that I believe to be pertinent, but let me know if there's something else I can provide you with to help.

Here's my /proc/asound/card0/pcm2p/sub0/hw_params file:

```
access: MMAP_INTERLEAVED
format: S32_LE
subformat: STD
channels: 2
rate: 48000 (48000/1)
period_size: 1024
buffer_size: 8192
```

Here's the result of "amixer scontents"

```
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'PGA3.0 3 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA5.0 5 Master',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 80
  Front Left: Capture 56 [70%] [6.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 56 [70%] [6.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PGA6.0 6 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA7.0 7 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'PGA8.0 8 Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 32
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 32 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 DAC',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Isense Mixer',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Left I Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 2 [29%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Left V Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 1 [14%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 RX Channel Select',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'L,R' 'L,L' 'L,R' 'L,L+R' 'R,L' 'R,R' 'R,L+R' 'L+R,L' 'L+R,R' 'L+R,L+R'
  Item0: 'L,R'
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Right I Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 3 [43%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Right V Tag Select',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 7
  Mono: 1 [14%]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 Vsense Mixer',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt1316-1 XU24 Bypass',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 22 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC1' 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'DMIC3'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 23 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC1' 'MIC2' 'LINE1' 'LINE2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'DMIC4'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 24 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC2' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'MIC2'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 ADC 25 Mux',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC1' 'DMIC1' 'DMIC2' 'DMIC3' 'DMIC4'
  Item0: 'MIC1'
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU02',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Capture 119 [94%] [270.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU06',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Rear Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Rear Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0A',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 47 [37%] [0.00dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0C Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%]
  Front Right: 0 [0%]
  Rear Left: 0 [0%]
  Rear Right: 0 [0%]
  Front Center: 0 [0%]
  Woofer: 0 [0%]
  Side Left: 0 [0%]
  Side Right: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'rt714 FU0E Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%]
  Front Right: 0 [0%]
  Rear Left: 0 [0%]
  Rear Right: 0 [0%]
  Front Center: 0 [0%]
  Woofer: 0 [0%]
  Side Left: 0 [0%]
  Side Right: 0 [0%]
```

Comment: try ''alsamixer''